# Unit testing, assert equals if difference is not bigger than 1

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit4

Im new to Unit testing. I use Junit4, I have to compare two double numbers. But if difference is not longer than 1, it should pass.
For example:

```
Assert.assertEquals(240, 241); //should pass
Assert.assertEquals(240, 239); //should pass

Assert.assertEquals(240, 242); //should fail
Assert.assertEquals(240, 238); //should fail
```

Is there way to implement it?

Comment: You can use `Assert.assertEquals(a, b, 1.0);`

Answer (score 1):

Read the javadoc of [the method you have used](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double)):

> ```
> @Deprecated`  
> public static void assertEquals(double expected,
>                                 double actual)
> ```
>
> Deprecated. Use *assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double epsilon)* instead.

It tells you that this method is deprecated.
And even more kindly, it tells [what better method](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double)) to use instead.

> ```
> public static void assertEquals(double expected,
>                                 double actual,
>                                 double delta)
> ```
>
> Asserts that two doubles or floats are equal to within a positive delta.

You see, this method exactly fits your need. So you can simply use:

```
Assert.assertEquals(240, 241, 1.0); //will pass
Assert.assertEquals(240, 239, 1.0); //will pass

Assert.assertEquals(240, 242, 1.0); //will fail
Assert.assertEquals(240, 238, 1.0); //will fail
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Nikolai Shevchenko suggestion to use `Assert.assertEquals(a, b, 1.0);`

Please check [assertTrue](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean)) too

```java
Assert.assertTrue(Math.abs(240 - 241) <= 1)
```

Comment: This isnt good advice. It adds a useless level of indirection. If at all, you should recommend `assertThat` and hamcrest matchers. When you know those, you will never ever need another assert.